# Extract specific text from another csv using python in jupyternotebook

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goT1w.png) i have a list of long text in one column in a csv file (proposal.csv) under header "proposal" and this contains sentences including addresses (such as building name and postal code). i have another csv file (building.csv) with building names under the "building" column.

i like to extract all the building names from the sentences in the proposal column. is there a way to do this? i spend nearly a whole day trying to figure this out but cannot seem to get. i used the df.isin(keywords) method but it appears all as false although the building names are present in the proposal column.

example of a row in the proposal column - "i live in taj mahal and it is a very pretty place". i like to extract the term "taj mahal" as it is a buidling (and taj mahal is listed inside my building csv).

can help please? thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

"df" will be the data frame that contains the sentence.

"df1" will contain the building name.

```
building = df1['building'].tolist()
for sentence in df['proposal'].tolist():
    for sent in sentence.split():
        if sent in building:
            print("'{}' found from the sentence '{}'".format(sent, sentence))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i tried but i am getting the error as "'str" object has no attribute 'spilt". any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you please show your logs because the split is a function of a string so there might be some other issue

Comment: i edited the initial query with the screenshot of the logs. cannot seem to add a screenshot in this comment reply.